# Why I have different results for 'same' thing?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to mention that I'm new to Node.js in general but I'm not sure why for the following code will give me different outputs in console for `questions` and `allQuestions` variable ?

```
var models = require('./models')(mongoose);
var query = models.Question.find({});

var questions = Array();

query.exec(function(err, allQuestions){
  //catch the error;
  questions = allQuestions;
  console.log(allQuestions);

});

console.log(questions);
```

Output of questions variable will be only: `Mongoose: questions.find({}) { fields: undefined }`   while `allQuestions` will contain all the questions from database.

I need to know why ?

Also I need that my `question` variable contains `allQuestions` from database.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `query.exec()` runs the function you passed as parameter asynchronously and the last line `console.log(questions);` will be executed before the callback is.

If you need the value of `questions`, then use another callback:

```
var models = require('./models')(mongoose);
var query = models.Question.find({});

var questions = Array();

query.exec(function(err, allQuestions){
  //catch the error;
  questions = allQuestions;
  console.log(allQuestions);
  done();
});

function done() {
    console.log(questions);
    // handle `questions` here ...
}
```